# isEmpty condition inside ngFor in Angular

Tags: angular

i have a project in which i display doctor's daily schedule.

i have created an array called "dates" which contains next 7 dates in string form

i have a time packet like class called scheduleTime

which have

```
export class ScheduleTime{
    date: string;
    hours: number;
    minutes: number;
}
```

i recieve an array called as "Schedule Time"of scheduleTime type which contains the date ,hours and minutes

and i display it accordingly

and here is my html code

```
       <div *ngFor="let Date of dates; let z = index" class="dateBox">
                     <div *ngFor="let time of ScheduleTime; let i = index">
                            <div *ngIf="Date == time.date">
                                <div class="timeSlots" [style.background-color]="startSelect>=0 && endSelect>0 && i>startSelect && i<endSelect?'rgb(207, 200, 238)':null" [ngClass]="{'startClass': time.hours == st.sh && time.minutes == st.sm && startDate == time.date, 'endClass': time.hours == et.eh && time.minutes == et.em && startDate == time.date}"
                                            (click)='timeSelector(time,i,todayDate)'>
                                            {{time.hours}}:{{time.minutes | zero}}
                                </div>
                    </div>
              </div>
         </div>
```

in this html code i print time slots for each next 7 dates by comparing the time packets

here is an example image:
[image: schedules display]

here is my relevant data stucode:

```
dates = [];

ScheduleTime: ScheduleTime[] = [];
```

the problem is : i want that if there are no time packets for particular date it should display "No available schedules"

Comment: can you provide the data structure of your variables dates, scheduleTIme

Comment: @Adityatoke did you mean this?

Answer (score 0):

On which you want to put the condtion and use that variable and in if put that html which you wanna show and in ng-template put like no record found or something.

```
   <div  *ngFor="let Date of dates; let z = index" class="dateBox">
<div *ngIf="ScheduleTime; else notExist";>
                         <div  *ngFor="let time of ScheduleTime; let i = index">
                                <div *ngIf="Date == time.date">
                                    <div class="timeSlots" [style.background-color]="startSelect>=0 && endSelect>0 && i>startSelect && i<endSelect?'rgb(207, 200, 238)':null" [ngClass]="{'startClass': time.hours == st.sh && time.minutes == st.sm && startDate == time.date, 'endClass': time.hours == et.eh && time.minutes == et.em && startDate == time.date}"
                                                (click)='timeSelector(time,i,todayDate)'>
                                                {{time.hours}}:{{time.minutes | zero}}
                                    </div>
                        </div>
                  </div>
</div>
    <ng-template #notExist>
            No available schedules
        </ng-template>
           </div>
```

Comment: @Shubham Sharma, please let me know if it does not fit in your question then i will try to share the alternate as per your question.

Comment: but if you will put that condition where you will check it exist then show rest does not show anything then i think it will not happen

Comment: please help in the relevance to my code..that would be very helpful.

Comment: In this for every date you are checking the all time list right then i think this is right but only thing you need to put the if condition in time where for which date there wont be any time in Scheduled list where you need to show the "No records"

Comment: please test with the given answer code that might help you.

Comment: if you could provide kind of Fiddle link where i can see your only little this view part and along with the dummy data will help me to resolve rest i have given code you have to try.

Comment: it gives this error "Can't have multiple template bindings on one element."

Comment: i have edited the answer,now use this will resolve the coming error.

Comment: are you available on linked in?

Comment: It is my request to you please understand the concept of how Conditions work in Angular so for that please follow this editor link where i have some conditions that will help you "https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-feumnt?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html"

Comment: you can find me here https://www.linkedin.com/in/charanjit-singh-b7b440a9